# How to extract from string with regex, a word and or condition

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'd like to extract a word from a string, but don't know how to proceed :

Say I have these character strings :

```
a_toto_matthew
a_tutu_matthew
```

In both cases, I'd like to extract **matthew**

I tried

```
gsub("^a_[toto|tutu]_(.*)$", "\\1", "a_toto_matthew")
```

But it doesn't work.
I could have done :

```
gsub("^a_.*_(.*)$", "\\1", "a_toto_matthew")
```

But I find it less elegant. I'd like to know the syntax for mentioning "toto" or "tutu" in the regexpr

Thanks in advance for any guidance,

Mathieu

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be using a capturing group matching u or o and a backreference and for the word use `\w+` or match any word char except an underscore.

```
^a_t([uo])t\1_([^\W_]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBoCTs/1)

In the replacement use group 2

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
gsub('a_(toto|tutu)_(.*)', '\\2', x)
#[1] "matthew" "matthew"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `stringr` with positive lookbehind

```
x <- c("a_toto_matthew", "a_tutu_matthew")
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=(toto|tutu)_)\\w+")
#[1] "matthew" "matthew"
```

Or using non-capturing group in `str_match`

```
stringr::str_match(x, "(?:toto|tutu)_(\\w+)")[,2]
```